# how to enable various cache in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-2.0

I have researched on the same but there is no any detailed tutorial available, using which any new user of cakephp can start work on that.

**What I want to do:**

how to enable all cache : view,query,any other if is there(which changes needed in core.php and in any other file)

**What I did**

I tried to enable cache, by reading documentation from cakebook

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html

but nothing working for me, and most important **how to check that cache is working or not**?

Comment: Did you also disable debug mode? File cache at least usually is not active in debug mode. You can see if it's working when files start to file up in your tmp/cache/views folder.

Comment: yes I tried but there is no any files in tmp/cache/views may be am missing something please can you suggest step by step

Comment: I think you are on the wrong page if you want view caching. This part of caching only addresses "lower" caching - in the middle of the code. And more importantly: Why? Is your app already finished and "productive"? Caching usually is added on top of the existing application when actually the need for it arose, not just for fun.

Comment: am not getting please can you give me example,please....